# Why can't I see the menu I created?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

So I'm creating a small wpf application for fun, and I want it to have a menu. I created the menu and what not, but when I run the program the menu doesn't show up at all. The code for the menu is currently:

```
<Window x:Class="TBA_Alpha.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TBA LogIn" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="tbPsw" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" SelectionBrush="Black" Background="White">
        <PasswordBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </PasswordBox.BorderBrush>
    </PasswordBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbUId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="214,94,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" SelectionBrush="Black">
        <TextBox.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
        </TextBox.Background>
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="LogIn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="239,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,73,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your UserID:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="214,122,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" BorderThickness="1">
        <MenuItem Header=" New " RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="63" Height="36" Background="White" Visibility="Visible" AllowDrop="True" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <MenuItem Header=" User " Click="newUser"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

any help whatsoever would be largely appreciated thank-you.

Edit: added the entire XAML code for the wpf, where the menu is near the end of the code

Edit: after removing all of the additional stuff and leaving only the headers, still experiencing the same problem

Edit: Tried the code in a different clean project and it worked, thank-you

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you posted. Have you tried omitting all properties except for the `Header` ones? Or perhaps any other code you've implemented that might cause such behavior? Perhaps other controls overlapping your menu?

Comment: In which control is this code contained? Perhaps a grid?

Comment: Probably the problem is not in this part of XAML. Can you post more/whole of XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that most of your controls use a `Magrin` attribute to separate themselves, rather than the functionality of the `Grid`. Since none of them specify the attached properties `Grid.Row`, they're all in the same row. Since `Menu` doesn't specify a `Margin`, it's at the top of the `Grid` and thus overlapping your other controls.

Try using actual grid rows

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <PasswordBox x:Name="tbPsw" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" SelectionBrush="Black" Background="White">
        <PasswordBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </PasswordBox.BorderBrush>
    </PasswordBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbUId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" SelectionBrush="Black">
        <TextBox.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
        </TextBox.Background>
        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="LogIn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your UserID:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Menu Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" BorderThickness="1">
        <MenuItem Header=" New " RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="63" Height="36" Background="White" Visibility="Visible" AllowDrop="True" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <MenuItem Header=" User " Click="newUser"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This isn't working either. I put it in a Grid.Row of it's own, and when I ran it still wouldn't show.

Comment: Try removing the `Height` and `Width` data, and double check that there are enough row definitions (there should be six)